# Uninstalling the Previous version of application installed: Installshield

Tags: installshield

I am working on Install shield 2013 Pro (Licensed version).
I created one installer(Version 1.00.000) which will install driver for wireless  network adapter .
Now i need to create an installer (Version 2.00.000) which must 'Uninstall Previous version ' installed in the PC.
I read sme forum which uses upgrade code for Uninstalling the version but could'nt get enough idea on this.
Can i get a well explained solution for this. Please help me in solving this issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The upgrade is done with the help of the upgradecode. This code must be the same for all product versions. This way Windows Installer can see two products are from the same family. The [support from Windows Installer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372379%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for controlling updates it also allows you to install allows you to decide the order of the upgrades, i.e. you can choose to first remove the old version and then install the new one, or to first install the new one and them remove the old version.

When doing upgrade you should also be careful on the package language and install type (per-user or per-machine). Windows Installer **does not** remove an older version if the install language or type is different from the one of the new version that is being installed.